# Lombok builder package scope

Tags: java, builder, lombok, access-modifiers, package-private

I would like to generate `package-scope` builder using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), but I'm not sure if it's possible (I didn't find any clues in [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder)).

By default Lombok generates `public` builder, i.e. this code:

```
@Builder
class User {

    private final String name;
}
```

Is translated into this:

```
class User {
    private final String name;

    User(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static User.UserBuilder builder() { // <-- how to make it package-private?
        return new User.UserBuilder();
    }

    public static class UserBuilder { // <-- how to make it package-private?
        private String name;

        UserBuilder() {
        }

        public User.UserBuilder name(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public User build() {
            return new User(this.name);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "User.UserBuilder(name=" + this.name + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to generate builder class without this leading `public` keyword?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the below in the [@Builder documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder):

> @Builder(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE) is legal (and will generate the builder class, the builder method, etc with the indicated access level) starting with lombok v1.18.8

And if you see the source code of Builder [here](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/Builder.java), you'll see that by default, the access level of a `@Builder` would be `lombok.AccessLevel.PUBLIC`, but can be made package-private with `@Builder(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)`.

Also FYI, the following access levels are supported by `@Builder` : `PUBLIC, MODULE, PROTECTED, PACKAGE, PRIVATE`. This is via the `AccessLevel` enum's source code [here](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/AccessLevel.java).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had an older version of Lombok and that's why I haven't seen this feature (as you mentioned it's quite fresh).

Comment: @k13i happy to help :)